# Identify distinct data by comparing two columns

Tags: db2

I have a table as mentioned below:

```
column1 | column2 | column3
--------|---------|--------
E1      | AA12345 | 12345
E2      | BB12345 | 12345
E3      | CC12345 | 12345
E4      | CC12345 | 12345
E5      | DD12345 | 12345
```

I need the rows that has same value in column3, but different value in column2 and should be more than 1 row.

Can you please help?

Expected result: It should pick the rows E1 and E2

[image]

Comment: Why only E1 and E2?  Why not everything except E4?  SQL works on ["Sets"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)), or the collection of everything that matches a set of criteria.  So you can get the set of all rows that match the contents of `column3`, but you get _all_ rows.  What do you need to restrict it to only those two particular rows?

Comment: Since the values in Column 2 for E3 & E4 rows are same, so i don't need those rows.

Comment: ...okay, then what about E5?  Shouldn't that be there too?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
select * from my_table where (column3, column2) in (
  select column3, column2 from my_table 
    group by column3, column2 
    having count(*) = 1
  );
```

This query will pick E1, E2, and E5. It won't pick E3, E4 since it's duplicated.

Comment: It should not return E5 row also

Comment: What do you mean? E5 is also "different value in column2" as you say. Can you elaborate?

Comment: For every unique value in column3, there has to be two different values in column2.

Comment: Then, this solution is good: `AA12345` is different from p `BB12345`, that is different from `DD12345`. There must be something you are thinking, that you are not saying :)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Thanks for the solution, It helps.